# Упал(,) как подкошенный(,) навзничь. Запятые

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

> Упал как подкошенный навзничь.
>
> Упал, как подкошенный, навзничь.

Встретила написание и с запятыми, и без. В чём отличие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Упал, как подкошенный, навзничь.**

В таком виде "как подкошенный" — это обстоятельство, выраженное сравнительным оборотом, поэтому выделяется запятыми.

2. **Упал как подкошенный навзничь.**

В таком виде "упал как подкошенный" — это фразеологизм, целиком является сказуемым, а "навзничь" — это обстоятельство. Запятая факультативна.

3. **Упал как подкошенный, навзничь.**

Возможен и такой вариант. Здесь сказуемое — "упал", а "как подкошенный" и "навзничь" — это однородные обстоятельства (обстоятельства образа действия, или степени), между ними ставится запятая, если нет союза.

*Лично мне второй вариант нравится меньше других, потому что в нём возникает странно звучащее выражение* "подкошенный навзничь", *так что не сразу и поймёшь, что к чему.*

Comment: Для сравнения не хватает существительного, а то не сильно понятно, с чем сравнивается, ведь это слово редко используется.

Comment: Мне уже кажется, что сравнение нецелесообразно. *Упасть так, как падает подкошенный.* А как он падает, чтоб с этим сравнивать? Подкошенные, например пьяные, падают не резко, а плавно. И то они обычно не падают, так как стараются держаться на ногах. Смысл сравнивать? Более того, возможно, что человек не может быть подкошенным, ведь подкашиваются именно ноги.

Comment: @oleedd вы ещё сутки покрутите вопрос в голове — вообще понимать его перестанете :) А "подкошенный" — это от слова "косить": видели когда-нибудь, как падает травостой, чиркнутый под корень косой?

Comment: Нет, не видел. Мне казалось, что это про человека с подкошенными ногами.

Comment: Ну тогда тем более требуется существительное — чтобы понимать, с чем сравнивается (трава там подкошенная, или пшеница, или ещё что). Сравнение нецелесообразно, потому что у многих людей нет представления об этом. Выражение уже стало чистым фразеологизмом.

Comment: @oleedd вы допускаете популярную ошибку: меряете многих по себе. Если вам или даже вашему кругу что-то неизвестно, это не означает автоматически, что оно многим неизвестно :)

Comment: Вы считаете, что все люди живут в сёлах и орудуют косой? Или же что все смотрят ролики, где орудуют косой? Косой уже мало кто пользуется. Жители городов — это уже многие. Вывод такой: сравнивать так можно, когда очевидно, с чем именно сравнивается. Здесь же в любом случае неясно, какое там растение имеется в виду.

Comment: @oleedd я считаю, что у тех, кто вообще использует оборот "как подкошенный", достаточно широкий кругозор. Я, к примеру, тоже не в селе живу.

Comment: Это довольно известный фразеологизм. Но использовать "упал так, как подкошенный" можно, разве что если собеседнику известно, что имеется в виду сухостой (слово тоже далеко не самое известное). Писать так для всех не следует, потому что далеко не всем будет понятно.

Comment: "Упал так, как срубленный" — вот так бы звучало сравнение "упал, как подкошенный", не будь оно фразеологизмом. Не хватает существительного.

Answer (score 3):

Наиболее корректная  запись выглядит так: ***Упал как подкошенный,  навзничь.***

**Пояснение**

1. В предложении два обстоятельства. Для определения знаков нужно определить **вид отношений между ними.**
2. **Значения слов и выражений**: КАК ПОДКОШЕННЫЙ: моментально, одним движением рухнуть из стоячего положения; НАВЗНИЧЬ,  нареч. На спину, на спине лицом вверх. Лечь, упасть н. Повалить кого-л. н.

Итак, упал мгновенно, упал лицом вверх. Семантика **неоднородная**, обозначена скорость падения и положение тела.

3. Теоретически возможны **три варианта:** нет запятых (неоднородные отношения),  одна запятая (однородные отношения), две запятые (уточнение).

**Для уточнения** особых причин нет:  оба обстоятельства равноправны в смысловом отношении. **Запись без запятых** выглядит неестественно и фактически не встречается на практике. А вот **однородные отношения** возможны, если считать обстоятельства СБЛИЖЕННЫМИ, раскрывающими одну тему (как упал).
К тому же фразеологический оборот обычно следует после сказуемого и примыкает нему.

4. **Пример из ответов Грамоты.ру.** Вопрос № 291154.  Подскажите, верны ли запятые…

Ответ справочной службы русского языка: *В этот момент немецкие пули поражают штабс-капитана и он падает навзничь, **как подкошенный**.*  Здесь, как мы видим, обозначены однородные отношения.

А это пример с обособлением и инверсией: Следом раздался выстрел. *Керим, **как подкошенный,** упал навзничь.* Л. А. Чарская.

Comment: *Для уточнения особых причин нет* — но может быть присоединение (так лучше всего звучит). Или вы про две запятые? Тогда не уточнение, а вклинивание оборота, например: *Он двигался, как гепард, быстро.*

Answer (score 1):

Сочетание ‟как подкошенный” пишется без запятой, так как это устойчивое сочетание. [Ссылка на правило (пункт 4, подпункт 6)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147). Вот пара примеров:

> Олени отбежали немного и остановились как вкопанные (Арс.).
> У Льва как гору с плеч свалило (Кр.).

Перед ‟навзничь” (на спину) может как стоять запятая, так и не стоять:

1. Запятая не ставится, когда слово ‟навзничь” является первостепенным для смысла — автор произносит предложение чтобы сообщить характер падения. Перед ‟навзничь” нет паузы.
2. Запятая ставится, когда слово ‟навзничь” носит присоединительный характер — автор произносит уже имеющее некий завершенный смысл предложение , а потом ,после паузы, решает дополнить его неким словом или сочетанием. Вот пара примеров присоединений из Розенталя:

> Довольно поздно явился ещё гость, во фраке (Герц.).
> Он умер, в Томске (М. Г.).
> Ночью я стою у орудия, дневальным (Кат.).

Comment: У Розенталя написано: "Запятая перед *как* **обычно** (выделение моё —N.) отсутствует, если сравнительный оборот выступает в роли сказуемого". Я полагаю, в таких вопросах хорошо указать все варианты, даже необычные.

Comment: Сказуемое — ‟упал как подкошенный”.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что "обычно" не равно "обязательно".

Comment: Я не понял, что вы хотите сказать. Перед ‟как подкошенный” нет запятой, так как ‟упал как подкошенный” — устойчивое сочетание. Я вообще ничего не писал про сказуемое.

Comment: Во-первых, строго говоря, устойчивое сочетание "как подкошенный", а не "упал как подкошенный". Во-вторых, Розенталь в примечании к указанному вами параграфу уточняет, имея в виду устойчивые сочетания, о которых говорилось им раньше, что "Запятая обычно отсутствует, если сравнительный оборот выступает в роли сказуемого". Так вот я уточняю: "обычно" не значит "всегда". *Сальные свечи… берегли как зеницу ока* (С.-Щ). Но: *― Педро, этого мальца нужно беречь, как зеницу ока: от его здравия зависит судьба многих людей!*

Comment: Так же и с другими устойчивыми оборотами. Вы приводите пример с "остановились как вкопанные", а вот случай, когда этот оборот дан без учёта его фразеологичности: "Через секунду Москвич смог оценить эластичность тормозов знаменитого спортивного автомобиля, когда они с ходу влетели под навес маленького гаража и остановились, как вкопанные". Или вот: " Булгаков наставится ухом на Лосского; глаза уходят в свое; головою, поставленной набок, на ухо наматывает; глаза ― бегают, остановились, как вкопанные; и морщина прорезалась..." (Андрей Белый).

Comment: Во-первых, там ничего не сказано про сказуемое, пункт 4 — перечисление всех случаев без запятой. Во-вторых подобное устойчивое сочетание входит в состав сказуемого.

Comment: Прям-таки "всех" случаев? Вот эта ваша безапелляционность, игнорирование обтекаемых выражений типа "Обычно" или "Другие примеры", и не позволяет, как мне кажется, вам видеть варианты пунктуации маловероятные, но возможные.

Comment: Всяких случаев без запятой, пожалуйста. В этом пункте не идет речь о сказуемом, об этом речь.

Comment: Ладно; я, кажется, недостаточно ясно выражаюсь. Забейте)