# Знаки препинания перед союзом «как»

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, как, сравнительный-оборот

Читая карманный справочник "Русский язык. 7–11 классы" издательства "Легион", я увидел один непонятный для меня случай, в котором запятая перед **как** ставится.
В справочнике он описан так:

> **Не выделяются запятыми** — если оборот имеет характер устойчивого сочетания и является сказуемым или тесно с ним связан: *Дождь лил **как из ведра***.
> **Но**: подобные обороты могут и выделяться запятыми в том случае, если они являются уже придаточной частью: *С вершины все окрестности видны, **как на ладони***.

Не являются ли слова после **но** ошибкой?
Если не являются, можете ли вы объяснить, как понять, в каких случаях оборот с характером устойчивого сочетания может быть придаточной частью?

Comment: Это обсуждали здесь под принятым ответом: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470057

Answer (score 1):

Запятую можно ставить тогда, когда, не зная фразеологизм, можно без проблем понять смысл. В таких случаях уместна подстановка "так":
*С вершины все окрестности видны так, как на ладони.* || Не очень понятно, что за ладонь. Это неудачный пример. Не хватает слов для нормального сравнения, одного обстоятельства "на ладони" мало, добавим слова:
*С вершины все окрестности видны так, будто они на ладони.*
А вот хороший пример:
*На Матвея с обеих сторон улицы глядели занавешенные окна домов, похожих друг на друга [так], как две капли воды.* || В таких случаях мы делаем логическое ударение на слове до "как".